# Hadoop: Does only number of splits decide on number of Map tasks or is it also something else?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Among pasts exams at my university I have such a question:

In the execution of a MapReduce job, whose input is a file partitioned and stored into 10
chunks by means of HDFS, the number of Map tasks

1. must be equal to 10
2. **can be 20 <- CORRECT**
3. is 1

All the sources say that it is the file partitioning that influence the number of Map tasks, so it should be 10, but the answer provided indicates "can be 20". I know that "must be equal" in 1) answer is a bit much, but I don't have any idea about when could it be different than 10. **Does anyone know why could it be 20?**

Comment: How large is each chunk? File/"Chunk" size matters

Comment: @OneCricketeer, it is not given. How does it matter? Would you elaborate on that please as it seems to be an explanation?

Comment: Say you upload a 1GB file into HDFS. This is split into several chunks (or rather blocks), per `dfs.blocksize`, which defaults to 128MB. Therefore, that 1GB file (if splittable file format when uploaded), which be split into about 8 blocks. Therefore, [up-to 8 mappers can read that data. But if the file is not splittable, then it is only 1 block, and only 1 mapper can read it](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Mapper)...  Doesn't really answer the question of how more than one mapper can be used per block, though